# How can I save the data when I return to my action and retrieve it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class and create an instance and fill a property in my index but when I push the submit button in my view and return again to my index action the property of my class is null.

How can I save the data when I return to my action and retrieve it? Is it possible?

I used `viewbag` and `viewdata` in my index and fill theme but when returned to index action again all of theme were null :(

```
public class myclass
{
    public string tp { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    myclass myc = new myclass();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        myc.tp = "abc";
        return View(myc);
    }
}
```

View:

```
 @model MvcApplication2.Controllers.myclass
 @{
  Layout = null;
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Index</title>
 </head>
 <body>

     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
     }

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use either GET or POST method in your Controller according to your form method like,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    myc.tp = id;
    return View(myc);
}
```

Comment: tp is my object property and fill in other part of my app it' not a parameter

Comment: your tb is empty in all cases, you are just assigning value in your index view, so you can pass the value and get the value from id, there is no other way you can keep. other than you try to get from service or db

Answer (score 0):

In your HttpPost you can get the model and see it's properties if you provided input fields for the properties in your view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(myclass myc)
{
    //check the myc properties here
    return View(myc);
}
```

Then in your View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tp)
```